# How to add request body to swagger docs without specifying it as a method parameter?

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-webapi, documentation, swashbuckle

I have a `.net core 2.0` Web API that uses `Swashbuckle` to generate the swagger documentation. There is one POST endpoint I need to specify the request body in the swagger documentation without specifying it as a `[FromBody]` method parameter of the controller. Can't specify this as a method parameter since the request body changes depending on the order type. I just want to specify the `BaseOrderModel` as the request model in swagger documentation. How should I accomplish this?

The following code snippet will give some understanding of my code.

```
// Contoller
[HttpPost]
[Route("checkout")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(CheckoutOrderDto), (int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CheckoutOrderAsync([FromQuery] OrderType type)
{

    BaseOrderModel? order;

    switch (type)
    {
        case OrderType.Pickup:
            // Deserialize to PickupOrder model
            break;
        case OrderType.Delivery:
            // Deserialize to DeliveryOrder model
            break;
        case OrderType.UberEats:
            // Deserialize to UberEats model
            break;
        default:
            return BadRequest("Invalid order type");
    }

    // Omitted rest of method for brevity
}

// Enum
public enum OrderType
{
    Pickup,
    Delivery,
    UberEats
}

// Models
public abstract class BaseOrderModel
{
    // Omitted props for brevity
}

public class PickupOrder : BaseOrderModel
{
    // Omitted props for brevity
}

public class DeliveryOrder : BaseOrderModel
{
    // Omitted props for brevity
}

public class UberEats : BaseOrderModel
{
    // Omitted props for brevity
}
```

Comment: if the request body changes depending on the order type what do you expect to see in Swagger?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I'm thinking if there is a way to change the request body depending on the `OrderType` query param drop-down on the swagger UI. If that's not possible displaying the `BaseOrderModel` on the swagger would be sufficient.

Comment: It is not possible. Swagger UI doesn't support such behavior. This is not .NET related staff. You need https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui. What is the problem with `BaseOrderModel`? Just add `[FromBody] BaseOrderModel requestsBody`

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Thank you for your responses. So looks like it is not possible. Also, can't add `[FromBody] BaseOrderModel requestsBody` as a method parameter since `BaseOrderModel` is an abstract class.

Comment: Don't keep it abstract if possible. Use interfaces